# Trouble with divs as image links floated next to eachother

Tags: wordpress, html, css-float

**ATTENTION! PROBLEM SOLVED, SOLUTION PASTED BELOW INITIAL QUESTION**

on the very top of web page Im working I have on to the left corner a flag (to change language) which I have in a div. On the right I have another div for another image (shop cart) but since I floated the right div, I still go to the right divs address when clicking on the left, like the right overrides the let one. Why? How can I solve this?

Also, I am doing this by using my html/css-files and editing them to fit wordpress for a customer.

**CSS**

```
#topmenu img {
    margin-left: 25px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#cartmenu img {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 542px;
}
```

**header.php**

```
 <div id="container">
   <div id="topmenu">
     <a href="http://wwgrgrhbhop.se/indexEU"><img src="wp-content/themes/blank/images/icon_en_global.png" alt="English.png" width="42" height="30"></a>
   </div>
   <div id="cartmenu">
     <a href="http://www.enerfergeggyshop.se/"><img src="wp-content/themes/blank/images/cart.png" alt="cart.png" height="" width=""></a>
 </div>
```

// **SOLUTION** Set width (in css) to both elements as well a float:left to both elements, then position with margins to get them where you want.

```
#topmenu img {
margin-left: 25px;
float:left;
position:relative;
width: 42px;
height:45;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:-10px;

}

#cartmenu img {
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 520px;
    float left;
    width:350px;
    height:40px;
    margin-top:-20px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to define a width for `#topmenu img` and giving the cartmenu a `float:left;` as well.

Comment: Yes you are correct after some more editing in the css i got it to work! I added the solution in my min post, thanks a lot =)